# the type closure does not fulfill the required lifetime

Tags: rust

I had a code similar to this:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mut prefe: Prefe = Prefe::new();
    start(&prefe).join();
    println!("Test {}", prefe.cantidad);
}

fn start(pre: &Prefe) -> thread::JoinHandle<i32> {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(50));
        let t: i32 = 3 as i32;
        t
    })
}
```

But when trying to use this:

```
std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(pre.minutos_pom_corto));
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/main.rs:15:19: 22:6 pre:&Prefe]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     thread::spawn(move || {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: type must outlive the static lifetime
```

After reading some things and [Arc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), I have this code which seems to work:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let mut prefe: Prefe = Prefe::new();
    let test = Arc::new(prefe);
    start(test).join();    
    //println!("Test {}", prefe.cantidad); // <- With this commented
}

fn start(pre: Arc<Prefe>) -> thread::JoinHandle<i32> {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(pre.minutos_pom_corto));
        let t: i32 = 3 as i32;
        t
    })
}
```

Without commenting `println!("Test {}", prefe.cantidad);`, I get this error:

```
 let test = Arc::new(prefe);
    |                ----- value moved here
```

I tried the following:

```
//..
let test = Arc::new(&prefe);
//..

fn start(pre: Arc<&Prefe>) -> thread::JoinHandle<i32> {
```

But I get an error similar to the first one

```
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/main.rs:19:19: 26:6 pre:std::sync::Arc<&Prefe>]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     thread::spawn(move || {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: type must outlive the static lifetime
```

I tried the following changes but it still does not work:

```
    //..
    let test = Arc::new(&prefe);
    start(&test).join();
    println!("{}", prefe.cantidad);
    //..

fn start(pre: &Arc<&Prefe>) -> thread::JoinHandle<i32> {
```

```
    //..
    let test = Arc::new(&prefe);
    let f = test.clone();
    start(&f).join();

    println!("{}", prefe.cantidad);
    //..

fn start(pre: &Arc<&Prefe>) -> thread::JoinHandle<i32> {
```

How can I fix this error, or what is the correct way to do what is shown?

Comment: TL;DR: There's no guarantee that your reference to `Prefe` will live longer than the thread does. You need to transfer ownership to the thread instead. You can use `Arc` to have shared ownership, but you need to explicitly `.clone()` it before giving it away if you need to keep ownership.

Comment: Really your comment, it was the one that helped me do this `let test = Arc::new(prefe); let f = test.clone(); start(f).join(); println!("{}", test.cantidad);` thanks again.